# Finding area bounded by curve

Tags: calculus

Find the first quadrant area bounded by curves: $y=\arctan(x)$, $y=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, $x=0$.
I am completely new to this kind of topic. So, someone help me please.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your own efforts to get answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

The area of y=arctanx is the same as that of the area of y=tanx as they both are just themselves reflected across y=x.
so our desired area is

$\int_0^{\pi/4}\tan y\, dy=\left[\log|\sec y|\right]_0^{\pi/4}={\small\frac{1}{2}}\log2.$

Comment: -@Venkat Amith, Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: ok @SarGe, I will make sure from the next time.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the integration are $x\in(0,1)$ and $y\in(\arctan(x),\dfrac{\pi}{4})$, so
$$\int_0^{1} \int_{\arctan(x)}^{\pi/4} dydx=\int_0^{1}(\dfrac{π}{4}- \arctan(x))dx=\int_0^{1}\dfrac{π}{4}dx-\int_0^{1}\arctan(x)dx=\dfrac{\log2}{2}$$

Comment: -@psidaga, Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Comment: A user asked for his attempt but he wrote nothing, so I answered his question

Comment: This is not a homework site, so don't worry about users who just post question without any prior knowledge or attempt. [See this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: Ok, I'm quite new on this platform. For the next time I'll give hints or I'll wait for the attempts of the "askers". Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The upper limit of integration can be derived from
\begin{equation}
\arctan{x}=\pi/4
\end{equation}
while the lower limit is obviously $0$.

Next, the integral used should be
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan{x} \,dx
\end{equation}
where a and b are the limits of integration derived in the previous step.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Hints . Should go to the comments, not to the answers.

Comment: @KurtG. alright